# Adjust the height of individual jupyter notebook cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The `custom.css` works very well for adjusting the width of a `jupyter` notebook (and the `font size` while we are at it..):

```
.container { width:100% !important; height: 200px; }
.CodeMirror pre {font-family: Monaco; font-size: 9pt;}
```

The cell ***height*** is trickier however since we do not want *all* cells to be made overly tall.

Here is an example of a cell "wanting" more vertical headroom:

[image]

Is there a per-cell approach to achieve this? There are actually two parts to this question:

- How to do this for `python` kernels (probably the easiest):
- How to change the cell height for other kernels: specifically we are interested in `R` and `Spark`

Comment: Do you want to change size of selected cell? If not how do you want to choose cells should have different size?

Comment: Yes cell-by-cell height change as mentioned in the question `per-cell approach`

Comment: From reading this [article](https://gist.github.com/paulochf/f6c9ed0b39f85dd85270) it seems that the problem could be solved by rewriting your css and html file. Also from the looks of it, it seems you would have to configure them after you've written all the cells and determined which cells need more height.

Comment: `rewriting css and html `
That may well be required presently: and that's not going to work since I need self contained `.ipynb` files to distribute with the team

Comment: Even as a temporary hack, `.container { width:100% !important; height: 200px; }` produces strange results as it resizes the header/toolbar section and messes up the scrolling. Would be great to see an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hacky, but the python flavor of this can be done using jquery and some IPython functions that let you execute javascript inline within a cell.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
```

This will let you execute javascript from anywhere in any cell like this:

```
display(HTML("<script>alert('Hello, World!');</script>"))
```

Then we mix that with some jquery and a few known classes that are on Jupyter div elements and we can change the output_wrapper size of the executed cell to whatever it needs to be:

```
display(HTML("<script>$('div.cell.selected').children('div.output_wrapper').height(50);</script>"))
```

If you don't want to re-run the code in that cell again, insert a cell above the one you want to change and tweak it to select the next cell div and update the height:

```
display(HTML("<script>$('div.cell.selected').next().height(100);</script>"))
```

Wrapping these with helper functions would be easy and worth while if it was needed on multiple cells.

This obviously won't be kept when the notebook is closed or reloaded. For that, you could improve this by adding a cell metadata attribute, then put something in the custom.js that reads and renders as needed.